# Error when using requests In Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://bbs.byr.cn/')
print r
```

The error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:\MyPythonRoad\src\requeststest.py", line 1, in 
>       import requests   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests__init__.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from . import utils   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\utils.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\compat.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from .packages import chardet   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\packages__init__.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       from . import urllib3   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\packages\urllib3__init__.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       from .connectionpool import (   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 36, in 
>       from .connection import (   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py",
>   line 43, in 
>       from .util import ( ImportError: No module named util

Comment: Go to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/packages/urllib3` and check to see if `util.py` is there.

Comment: It's not included util.py,how should I do next?  THX.

Answer (score 1):

### requests

Since you are using Windows, you may want to try to reinstall `requests` through this [binary](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#requests).

### urllib3

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361432/import-of-urllib3-util-failing-in-python-2-7), you may want to try manual download the `util` folder from `urilib3` from the download at the bottom of [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/urllib3/1.8.2), and add it to the `urllib3` install location.

Comment: Thank you,I just uninstall the latest version of requests and install requests 2.2.1,the problem solved!