# Import error for urllib3

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib3

I'm using Python 2.7 and am trying pull data from an API using a python script and urllib3. I've installed urllib3 by copying the source code but from GitHub. But, I'm still getting the following error when running the script:

```
ImportError: No module named urllib3
```

The script starts simply enough with:

```
import urllib3 
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
```

I've checked the urllib3 file, and it includes the [util file cited in other responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361432/import-of-urllib3-util-failing-in-python-2-7)

Answer (score 2):

> I've installed urllib3 by copying the source code but from GitHub.

Bad way to "install" `urllib3`.  Use this instead

```
pip install urllib3
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to copy that module directory (**urllib3/urllib3/**). you'll find __init__py file on that directory to that script's directory.

Another way:

```
$ pip search urllib3
opbeat_python_urllib3 (1.1)  - An urllib3 transport for Opbeat
apiclient (1.0.3)            - Framework for making good API client libraries using urllib3.
urllib3 (1.17)               - HTTP library with thread-safe connection pooling, file post,
                               and more.
httplib2shim (0.0.1)         - A wrapper over urllib3 that matches httplib2's interface
yieldfrom.urllib3 (0.1.4)    - Asyncio HTTP library with thread-safe connection pooling, file
                               post, and more.
urllib3-mock (0.3.3)         - A utility library for mocking out the `urllib3` Python
                               library.
```

Installing it using pip

```
pip install urllib3
```